# php: preg_replace_callback remove detected content with its patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

here is my string.

```
$string = '{TE:Hi}';
```

and this is my preg_replace_callback code:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('#(?<={TE:)(.*?)(?=})#is', function($matches){
        return '';
    }, $string);
```

i should use the preg_replace_callback because im using another function into callback function.
this code can replace the detected content and remove it.
but cant remove its patterns ( {TE: and  } )
this only remove "Hi" from string but i want to remove "{TE:Hi}".
"Hi" is dynamic and it can be something else. And there may be several patterns of this form in string.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the complete braced expression, then you should not use the `(?<=` nor `(?=` look-around. Just match:

```
#{TE:(.*?)}#is
```

Note that this will influence what is provided in the `$matches` array to the callback function.

It will be `["{TE:Hi}", "Hi"]` instead of `["Hi", "Hi"]`.